# dash and plotly - select points on graph programatically

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I built a simple web-app in dash where I have a scatterplot which the user can select points from. All the points that the user selects are shown in a text box output for visibility. All of this works fine, but the problem arises when I want to create a method that will pick points automatically and mark them on the plot. I want this to simulate the user's choices so the user may continue to interact with the plot as if he/she has chosen these points.
I have prepared a minimal example here:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll',
        'width': '80%'
    }
}


def get_figure():
    fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
    fig.update_layout({'height': 500,
                       'clickmode': 'event+select'})
    return fig


app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph1',
        figure=get_figure()
    ),
    html.Button('Generate random point clicks', id='generate-random-points-button'),
    html.Pre(id='selected-data', style=styles['pre']),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('graph1', 'figure'),
    Input('generate-random-points-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('graph1', 'figure')
)
def generate_random_point_clicks(n_clicks, fig):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return fig
    fig = go.Figure(fig)
    fig.update_traces(selectedpoints=random.sample(list(range(5)), 3))
    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output('selected-data', 'children'),
    Input('graph1', 'selectedData'))
def display_selected_data(selectedData):
    res = []
    if selectedData is not None:
        for point in selectedData['points']:
            res.append(str(point))
        return '\n'.join(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When you run this app this is how it will look like:
[image]

The problem is that I am updating `selectedpoints` attribute of the graph and not the `selectedData`. The points appear on the graph as if they are chosen but when the user clicks on more points all the automatic selections disappear. Plus I want the automatic selections to show in the text box. I tried updating `selectedData` via the callback but it didn't work for me.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you finally found solution?

Comment: I moved to streamlit :D